# CoffeScript adding a class with hover

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm learning how to use CoffeeScript with Ruby on Rails. I have this set up :

```
$ ->
  $this = $(this);
    $(".ind").hover(
  ->
      $this.addClass("hoverOver")
  ->
      $this.removeClass("hoverOver")
  );
```

and I have this in my css file

```
.hoverOver {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

But it doesn't work? If I change my code to test:

```
$ ->
  $this = $(this);
    $(".ind").hover(
  ->
      alert("in")
  ->
      alert("out")
  );
```

This works, but I don't understand why adding a class wouldn't work?

Comment: FWIW, you could do what you say in your example with just `.ind:hover { cursor: pointer; background-colour:#fff; }` in your CSS. Hopefully you have some other reason for adding a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As Jason mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15858708), you're adding the class to the document rather than to the element. One way to fix your code would be like this:

```
$ ->
  ind = $('.ind').hover \
    (-> ind.addClass 'hoverOver'), \
    (-> ind.removeClass 'hoverOver')
```

This, I think, captures your intention: caching the jQuery object. However, if there are multiple elements with the class `ind`, it will do all of them whenever any of them are hovered over. If you don't want that, then just use `$(this)` (or CoffeeScript's terse and unintelligible abbreviation, `$(@)`):

```
$ ->
  $('.ind').hover \
    (-> $(this).addClass 'hoverOver'), \
    (-> $(this).removeClass 'hoverOver')
```

Comment: What does the slashes mean?

Comment: I knew there was some CofeeScript way of doing this. +1

Comment: @andrewliu: They mean "I'm going to continue this statement on the next line, so don't you throw a parse error at me for doing that!"

Comment: Thank you! CoffeeScript is fun

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are adding your class to the document and not the element you are hovering over. You are assigning $(this) to a var named $this then you are attaching a hover callback but using $this to attach the class (defined outside of the hover callbacks). You could change the $this to $(this)

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses on function calls are often optional but putting them in anyway can make things clearer and less noisy:

```
$('.ind').hover(
  -> $(@).addClass 'hoverOver'
  -> $(@).removeClass 'hoverOver'
)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gXKTP/

You could also name your callbacks, this is especially useful when your callbacks get larger:

```
hover   = -> $(@).addClass 'hoverOver'
unhover = -> $(@).removeClass 'hoverOver'
$('.ind').hover hover, unhover
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kXcFM/

Or just cut out all the noise and use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and the single argument form of [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2):

```
$('.ind').hover -> $(@).toggleClass 'hoverOver'
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gXKTP/

I've also localized the targeted element in all three cases but [icktoofay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15858720/479863) has already pointed that problem out.